# Master Slave JK Flip flop

Tags: digital-logic

In Master Slave JK flip flop

1. Is the master positive level triggered or positive edge triggered?
   2)Is the slave negative edge triggered?

I have searched many websites but different answers in all of them

Comment: Look at the data sheets for the various Flip Flops you are wondering about. Follow the logic flow for each device. Also look at the state tables for each device. The questions you are asking will be answered there.

Comment: Clarify your question please. Do you ask about NOT gate between two JK-flip-flops in a master JK-flip-flop?
http://barrywatson.se/dd/dd_jk_flip_flop_master_slave_schematic.png

Answer (score 1):

It can be both: It depends on how it's implemented. What matters is that, ideally, whenever one stage is in a certain state (say, Master is transparent), the other must be exactly in the opposite one (say, Slave is holding) so that they are mutually exclusive themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The master flip-flop is usually positive edge triggered, the slave flip-flop is usually negative edge triggered.

Comment: i think it is more appropriate to refer to the master and slave as **latches** that are **level sensitive**.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
If I give you just a clock signal you cannot tell if that clock signal is coming from an inverter or not. So, when you say "I have searched many websites but different answers in all of them", it seems fine to me because someone might be using an inverted clock signal from somewhere. But in general, master is always clocked at positive edge and slave at negative edge.

Answer (score 0):

There are both positive and negative edge triggered versions. It doesn't depend on it being a "slave" or a "master". It's just a logic gate.
They were called slave and master because they were once used in such configuration. But you can use them alone for other purpose (abolish slavery) and then it's up to you to choose which way it's triggered.